# Where should I call custom method in django CBV? (DetailView)

Tags: python, django

I made a custom method that save session when call `get()` method in `DetailView` page.

Here's sample of my code.

```
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Jobs
    template_name = "jobs/job_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "job"

    def custom_save_session(self, request):
        # save session and so on
    ...
```

I wonder where should I call `custom_save_session` method.
I tried to call it inside `get()`, `get_context_data()` and so on.

All work well, but I have curiosity what is the best method.

- Should I call inside `get()` method? Cause I want to save session data every time `get()` called.
- Is there any method that call custom method when every time `get()` called in `DetailView`?

(I also wonder not only `DetailView`, but also all `CBV` in django too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can call extra methods in class based `DetailView` in two ways.

1. By overriding `disatch` method
2. By overriding `get` method

## dispach method

```
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Jobs
    template_name = "jobs/job_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "job"

    def custom_save_session(self, request):
        pass
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.custom_save_session(request)
        return super(CustomDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

## get method

```
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Jobs
        template_name = "jobs/job_detail.html"
        context_object_name = "job"
    
        def custom_save_session(self, request):
            pass
        
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.custom_save_session(request)
            return super(CustomDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Both of the above ways is fine. But, I will go with `dispatch` method because we are dealing with session data so, it would be better.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot dispatch and as_view method!

Answer (score 1):

Every class based view has an order of running things, each with it's own method.

CBV have a dedicated method for each step of execution.

You would call your custom method from the method that runs the step where you want to call your custom method from.

So you have to decide where your custom method should run, and define your own method on top of the view generic method for this step.

[More from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)

In the url the CBV returns as_view(), which is callable function that gets a reuqest. From this entry point (actually the CBV dispatch method), the CBV runs all the steps.